# Why it is printing None even if I am returning list of tuples?

Tags: python

I want to sort the sample_list with last digit of the tuples in the list in increasing order.
I want to do that without using sorted. But here even if I am returning list with tuples it is printing None. If I print inside the function instead of returning the variable it will print expected result else it will print None.

Why it is printing None even if I am returning list of tuples?

```
    sample_List = [(2, 5), (1, 2), (4, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1)]
    # Expected Result = [(2, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), (2, 5)]
    
    
    def sort_list2(smp_list, new_list=[]):
        list_of_last_elements_of_tuples = [x[1] for x in smp_list]
        if smp_list == []:
            return_tup = new_list
            return return_tup
        
        for element in smp_list:
            if element[1] == min(list_of_last_elements_of_tuples):
                new_list.append(element)
                smp_list.remove(element)
        sort_list2(smp_list, new_list)
    
    
    op = sort_list2(sample_List)
    print(op)
```

Comment: What happens when you flow out the bottom of the function?  What do you return?

Comment: Just add line `return new_list` to the very end of your sorting function, [like here](https://tio.run/##hVK9boQwDN7zFJa6JBI6Ce5uqcTYrVNXFCFUjIoESZSElnt6LuYC5Dq0HnBifz92hLn5L63Oy@Ka0QxYv/fOQwkVLzK4igx4nkFB@ZLBhXKon2POhWQv8DYb/PTYwge6adjJeUreSInINZAZa7EDp62vh@BbcDea9ZSBwp/1VFZSvDIIQbdad/XQhIwDjqi8o4KfwuCOfOcql9BpCzP0CjYxudL7bi9AGbDyoUph0U9WkU4Q2Yx/dRPQ2lk/ZBUnSQ0P5WAa@zRZsB17xf9ZRBx0im2eU2MMqpZHgngCbc4ni6P@xmfQn@/7gMQd990Z0/QWKfP4PQQztleeayOW5Q4).